# How to redirect this "Floating point exception(core dumped)" error?

Tags: bash, shell-script, stderr

I want to redirect the output of a program to a file with variable name and, at the same time, redirect the possible error. This is the script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Se ejecutará el PET-linux.x con PET.inp como input, debe indicarse el nombre del archivo output."
echo "Nombre del archivo .out: "
read outfile

./PET-linux.x < PET.inp > ${outfile}.out 2> /dev/null

echo $?
```

If I run the program knowing that it would make an error, I get this in the terminal:

```
samuel@samuel-P5Wx6:~/Documents/Fisica/19-20/Radiactividad/Prácticas/Practicas-MontCarlo/PET/pruebas$ ./ejecutarPET.sh 
Se ejecutará el PET-linux.x con PET.inp como input, debe indicarse el nombre del archivo output.
Nombre del archivo .out: 
test
./ejecutarPET.sh: line 7: 25715 Floating point exception(core dumped) ./PET-linux.x < PET.inp > ${outfile}.out 2> /dev/null
136
```

I know why this error happens, but I want it to not appear on the terminal like that. Can't I use `2>` at the same time as `>`?

Thank you.

Comment: The shell running the script is reporting the error, not the PET-linux.x program itself. The redirection only applies to the PET-linux.x program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585030/how-to-redirect-this-error/585047#comment1089423_585030), it is your shell script reporting the floating point exception from your application.

Modify the `PET-linux.x` line as follows, to catch the exception and exit silently. You can test for the exception by checking the return status for 136 and logging it as appropriate. (If you don't want the reporting, just omit that second line. I've included it so that you can see how you would identify a floating point exception programmatically if you needed to do so.)

```
( trap 'exit' SIGFPE; ./PET-linux.x < PET.inp > "$outfile.out" ) 2>/dev/null
[[ $? -eq 136 ]] && echo "Uh oh we caught a floating point exception" >&2
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot!